# Spring Security: Can I use LDAP and Digest Authentication together?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

Is there a way to use LDAP as an authentication backend with HTTP Digest as authentication method to the client with Spring? I could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LDAP as a `UserDetailsSService` for DIGEST, but **only** when you have access to user's password in clear text. Excerpt from [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html#digest-processing-filter):

> The configured UserDetailsService is needed because
>   DigestAuthenticationFilter must have direct access to the clear text
>   password of a user. Digest Authentication will NOT work if you are
>   using encoded passwords in your DAO. The DAO collaborator, along with
>   the UserCache, are typically shared directly with a
>   DaoAuthenticationProvider. The authenticationEntryPoint property must
>   be DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint, so that DigestAuthenticationFilter
>   can obtain the correct realmName and key for digest calculations.